# extjs nested data not displaying in databind grid

Tags: extjs, data-binding, grid

How do I databind my extjs6 grid to include "commission" using the following format I created from webapi ef?

grid columns should look like this.

```
title: 'Commissions',
xtype: 'grid',
bind: {
store: '{myAccountDetails.commission}'
},
ui: 'featuredpanel-framed',
cls: 'custom-grid',
margin: '0 0 0 0',
itemId: 'gridCommId',
collapsible: true,
columns: [
{
header: 'USD',
dataIndex: 'usd',
flex: 1
},
{
header: 'AUD',
dataIndex: 'aud',
flex: 1
},
{
header: 'CAD',
dataIndex: 'cad',
flex: 1
}
```

[image: screenshot]
This is my view of grid

the screenshot I attached is myAccountDetails

any help would be greatly appreciated!

just a sidenote... if I add a label I am able to return the info I am looking for but I want it to be inside a grid.

```
                    xtype: 'label',
                    cls: 'myLabelCRM2',
                    bind: {
                        text: '{myAccountDetails.commission.aud}'
                    }
```

Comment: What is `myAccountDetails`? A store? A data field in vm?

Comment: sorry, yes exactly, myAccountDetails is a data field in the view model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach is to define a store in viewmodel, and bind it's data field directly to the details commision field using the mustache syntax.

```
Ext.define('MyView', {
    viewModel: {
        data: {
            myAccountDetails: {
                accountName: 'foo',
                commision: {
                    aud: 7,
                    cad: 8,
                    usd: 9
                }
            }
        },
        stores: {
            commisionStore: {
                fields: ['aud', 'cad', 'usd'],
                data: '{myAccountDetails.commision}'
            }
        }
    },

    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'MyView',
    bind: {
        store: '{commisionStore}'
    },
    columns: [{
        header: 'USD',
        dataIndex: 'usd',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        header: 'AUD',
        dataIndex: 'aud',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        header: 'CAD',
        dataIndex: 'cad',
        flex: 1
    }]
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'MyView',
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks... in commissionStore that you created, how do I replace the fields you used with a model I have already created with those same fields?

Comment: `model: 'full.model.Name'`. Though personally I don't think models are useful, unless you want to use association feature

Comment: thank you... your example solves my issue!  for some reason when I put the model the grid is empty, but if I remove the model it works perfectly.  no clue why. thanks for your help